# What is the internal implementation of pandas Series.map()?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, numpy

I notice that pandas Series.map() is extremely fast for dict mapping

Prepare data as below:

```
a=np.random.randint(0,1000,10**5)
s=pd.Series(a)
d=dict(zip(np.arange(1000),np.random.random(1000)))
```

timing

```
%timeit -n10 s.map(d)
%timeit -n10 np.vectorize(d.get)(a)
```

gives

```
1.42 ms ± 168 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
20.6 ms ± 386 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

where the second approach is typical recommandation to do numpy dict mapping I found on stackoverflow.

There is another typical solution of numpy as below

```
%%timeit -n10 
b = np.copy(a)
for k, v in d.items():
    b[a==k] = v
```

which gives

```
43.9 ms ± 2.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

it is even slower, and what is worse, it gives wrong result. Because `b` is int type, assignment `b[a==k] = v` will return b will all zeros!

So I am wondering what is the internal implementation of pandas Series.map()? Does it implemented in numpy? What is the numpy equavalent to Series.map() that has the same performance? I tried to dig into the source code of Series.map() but can not understand it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Series.map` will call [`_map_values()`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/base.py#L1086-L1167) which is part of pandas/core/base.py

You're using a dict so you go through the first `if is_dict_like(mapper):` clause to get the `mapper`, and then on lines 1161-1162 you get the mapping function for this basic case (non-extension type with default `na_action=None`)

```
else:
    map_f = lib.map_infer
```

If you then go to that part of the code, found in pandas/_libs/lib.pyx you'll see [`map_infer` is implemented in `cython`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.0.0/pandas/_libs/lib.pyx#L2304-L2343).

---

As they note in the comments, this is only so fast for specific inputs:

```
# we can fastpath dict/Series to an efficient map
# as we know that we are not going to have to yield
# python types
```

Comment: Thank you so much for quick answer. I failed to trace lib.pyx. BTW, is it possible for an equivalent fast approach in numpy?

Comment: @user15964 yeah it wasn’t a simple thing to trace back. As per numpy I’m not sure, though I know there are a few very knowledgeable users on SO that would probably have an answer if you created a question around that.

Comment: `numpy` does not have an equivalent mapper.  In fact it doesn't do anything special with dictionaries.  The `vectorize` code times the same as a list comprehension, `np.array([d[i] for i in a])`.  Pandas apparently is using one or more functions of custom compiled code (via the `pyx` and `cython`).